# Any performance concern when using $firebaseArray to add a new record to Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I got the following AngularJS sample code from the document regarding how to add a new record to Firebase. It works fine and the new record can be created successfully.

While I also noticed that from the callback we can get all the siblings with the list variable, which is interesting.

My question is that would there be any performance latency when the list is large, say 100,000 records. Can anyone shed light on this?

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$firebaseArray` synchronizes a collection from the Firebase Database to your client, for easy display in your Angular views. You should never synchronize more data than the user needs to see, and 100,000 records seems very much beyond what a user should ever see.

If you just want to add a new item, you're better off using the Firebase JavaScript SDK directly:

```
ref.push({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
});
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, it will pick up this change automatically.

Comment: Now I see when the two libraries fit for. Thanks to Frank.